# Creating overlays in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an overlay similar to this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw2nx.png) but can't seem to figure it out.

I tried using the absolute positioning but it doesn't seem to work for more than 1 child element.

Any way around this, please?

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.parent {
  border: 2px solid #0074d9;
  color: #0074d9;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.element {
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
}

.element2 {
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    Parent element
      <div class="element">Child element</div>
      <div class="element2">Second Child element</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a brief take on it.

I set the main container to `position: relative;`, so that any `position: absolute;` children are positioned relatively to the parent.

I make a child-container to hold all the children, and place it at the bottom (and slightly extending out of) the main container, by doing `top: 100%;` combined with `transform: translateY(-50%);`. This also has `display: flex;` on it, so that its children will align themselves side-by-side.

You can add or remove children as necessary and it will automatically accommodate.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 125px;
  background-color: #42b6f4;
}

.container>.main-text {
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.child-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}

.child-container > .child {
  flex-grow: 1; /* Children should grow to fill unoccupied space */
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px; /* Amount of space between children */
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-text">This is some main text</div>
  <div class="child-container">
    <div class="child">Child 1</div>
    <div class="child">Child 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Below is a version with borders on all elements, as to explain the concept a bit.**

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 125px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.container>.main-text {
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.child-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  border: 2px dotted green;
}

.child-container > .child {
  flex-grow: 1; /* Children should grow to fill unoccupied space */
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px; /* Amount of space between children */
  border: 2px dashed blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-text">This is some main text</div>
  <div class="child-container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<span style="color: red;">Parent Container</span><br>
<span style="color: green; margin-left: 15px;">Child Container</span><br>
<span style="color: blue; margin-left: 30px;">Child</span>
```

Comment: Thumbs up. Cleanest way of achieving desired result.

Comment: This works! However, it doesn't seem to be responsive, any way around that?

Comment: @mista_oba It definitely is responsive. :) If you click on "Full Page" on the right side of the snippet, and shrink the window, it will collapse to fit. [**(Screenshot)**](https://i.imgur.com/zgejrYe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your second child element is on top of the first child element.

1) Add position : relative to parent element

2) You have to use top, bottom, left, right css attributes to place your children elements wherever you want.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.parent {
  border: 2px solid #0074d9;
  color: #0074d9;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  position : relative;
}

.element {
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  top : 20;
  right : 0;
}

.element2 {
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  top : 20;
  left : 20;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    Parent element
      <div class="element">Child element</div>
      <div class="element2">Second Child element</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```